# SetBinding not registering for PropertyChanged event

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, propertychanged

In an application I'm working on, I programmatically create several FrameworkElements with differing data sources. Unfortunately, the data binding is failing.

I managed to distill the problem into the following program:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace TestBinding
{
    public class BindingSource : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }


        private string _text = "Initial Text";
        public string Text
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set { SetField(ref _text, value); }
        }
    }

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            tb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            tb.FontSize = 36;

            Binding bind = new Binding() { Source = bs.Text, Mode=BindingMode.OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged };
            tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, bind);

            Patergrid.Children.Add(tb);
        }

        private void ClickText1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bs.Text = "First text button clicked!";
        }

        private void ClickText2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bs.Text = "Second text button stroked!";
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestBinding.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestBinding"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="Patergrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="Text 1" Margin="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="ClickText1" />
            <Button Content="Text 2" Margin="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="ClickText2" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

By stepping through code when the properties are changed, I see that there are no subscribers to the PropertyChanged event.

Why isn't SetBinding registering for the PropertyChanged event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this instead:

```
Binding bind = new Binding()
{
    Source = bs,
    Path = new PropertyPath("Text"),
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
};
```

There seem to be two problems here:

1. The code you're posting attempts to using the `string` object returned by the `bs.Text` property, which is not an observable binding source. The binding system is flexible enough to copy the value once, but after that, there's no way for it to know that the object has changed (even if it could…and `string` is an immutable type, so the object won't ever change anyway).

Instead, you want to bind to the `BindingSource` object itself as the source, using the `Text` property as the path.

2. Also, it doesn't make sense to combine `BindingMode.OneWay` with any specific settings for `UpdateSourceTrigger`. When the binding mode is one-way, the source is never updated so it doesn't matter what the trigger is.

Using `BindingMode.TwoWay` will allow changes in the `TextBlock.Text` property to be copied back to the source.

Alternatively, just don't bother setting `UpdateSourceTrigger`. The `TextBlock` isn't user-editable anyway, so maybe you really did intend for the binding to be one-way and just left the extraneous initialization of `UpdateSourceTrigger` from something else. It's hard to know from your question which is right implementation for your needs.

Comment: I added the UpdateSourceTrigger as another answer on SO recommended it. It didn't help, and it's irrelevant to my needs, so I'll remove it.